# Communicating between to Eureka clients

Tags: spring-boot, client, netflix-eureka

I have two clients registered to the same Eureka server, when I check the server UI I see both clients registered fine. But when I try to call one client from the other I get IO exception: `ResponseEntity<LoginInformationDto> quoteResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://lirs-security/api/userSecurity/validateUserToken/" + token, HttpMethod.GET,
                        null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<LoginInformationDto>() {
                });
                /** ResponseEntity<LoginInformationDto> quoteResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8103/api/userSecurity/validateUserToken/" + token, HttpMethod.GET,
                        null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<LoginInformationDto>() {
                }); */` . When I access the other service directly it works. error: `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://lirs-security/cbf69488-5624-4181-9254-ff423afa7620": lirs-security; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: lirs-security`
 This is what my console looks like : [image]
I've been battling with this for days and I've ran out of ideas. I really need all the help I can get @ this point.

```
`#Server application.yml file
spring:
application:
name: lirs-gateway

server:
port: 8101
eureka:
instance:
hostname: localhost 
client:
registerWithEureka: false
fetchRegistry: false
#server:
#waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
serverUrl:
defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

#security client yml file
eureka:
client:
registerWithEureka: true
fetchRegistry: true
serviceUrl:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8101/eureka/
instance:
hostname: localhost

#Security client properties file
spring.application.name=lirs-security
server.port=8103

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/***** 
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming- 
strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy 

#tax payers client yml
eureka:
client:
registerWithEureka: true
fetchRegistry: true
serviceUrl:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8101/eureka/
instance:
hostname: localhost

# client properties file
spring.application.name=tax-payers
server.port=8102

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming- 
strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
security.oauth2.client.clientId=myID
security.oauth2.client.scope=bigScope
simpleProp=this is the value`

`@EnableDiscoveryClient
//@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class TaxpayersApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TaxpayersApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}


}

@EnableDiscoveryClient
//@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class LirsSecurityApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LirsSecurityApplication.class, args);
}
}`
```

Comment: Can you post your application.yml or application.properties? Also the class where you used @EnableDiscoveryClient

Comment: I've added the updates above

Answer (score 7):

Eureka is intended for **locating services**. It means that you should not hard code any URLS in your clients. Basic example of two eureka clients integration should looks like following:

1) Eureka server:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: SERVER1
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  server:
    hostname: localhost
```

2) First application:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app_1
server:
  port: 0
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

3) Second application:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app_2
server:
  port: 0
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

So we have two apps registered in eureka server.

Now the idea is to request needed app URL from eureka server and use it.

First app code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
public class ClientApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
     RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    private EurekaClient discoveryClient;

    @RequestMapping("/greetingTest")
    public String greetingTest() {
        String url = discoveryClient.getNextServerFromEureka("APP_2", false).getHomePageUrl();
        return restTemplate().getForEntity(url + "/greeting", String.class).getBody();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        return "I'm first app";
    }
}
```

Second app has same code except this line:

```
discoveryClient.getNextServerFromEureka("APP_2", false)
```

It will use APP_1 as service name. So basically first app requests second app URL and vice versa.

So calling first APP using `/greetingTest` path will result in - "I'm second app" whereas calling second APP using `/greetingTest` path will result in - "I'm first app" which means that they are integrated successfully.

For further reading you could use spring cloud [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.0.0.M8/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_service_discovery_eureka_clients).